# How do I stop this loop from repeating once the user has entered the correct answer?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm only just beginning to learn to code in java and I've tried to figure this out for a **while** now, I've tried various methods and I've tried looking through similar questions but I can't find my answer.

I'm trying to get the loop to repeat while the user's input does not equal to 1, 2, or 3. Then stop repeating once a correct answer is entered.

```
    // create a menu and display it to the user
    // then ask the user to choose an option
    String menu = "1) See Rules\n"
                + "2) Play the Game\n"
                + "3) Exit\n"
                + "Please enter your choice: (1 or 2 or 3) ";

    String userChoice = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(menu);

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You chose option " + userChoice); 

    // display the rules
    String rules = "Rules:\n"

            + "The game will display total 3 multiple choice questions," +
            " with 4 possible answers per question.\n"
            + "Once you answer the question, the correct answer will be displayed" +
            " and the game will advance to the next question.\n"
            + "If you answer the question correctly, you will gain a point.\n"
            + "Each point is added to a total score that will be displayed at the" + 
            "end of the game.\n";

 // declare an integer that reads the user input
 int numericChoice = Integer.parseInt(userChoice);

 boolean valid = (numericChoice == 1 || numericChoice == 2 || numericChoice == 3);

 while (true)
 {
     if (!valid) {
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid selection, please try again");
         JOptionPane.showInputDialog(menu);
     } if (valid){ 
         break;
 }

    if (numericChoice == 1){
     // display the rules then start the game
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, rules);
    }
    else if (numericChoice == 2){
     // start the game
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Let's play the game.\n");
    }
    else if (numericChoice == 3)
     // exit the game
    System.exit(0);
```

Please help.

Comment: You never change `valid` so you shouldn't expect the loop to terminate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are computing **valid** *outside* of your loop.
In other words: you compute it once; before you enter the loop; and then, within your loop you never touch its value again.

Therefore, the "only" thing that your loop does is to raise that dialog over and over again.

Thus: you have to move **all** of those computations inside the loop!

So, not only

```
boolean valid = (numericChoice == 1 || numericChoice == 2 || numericChoice == 3);
```

needs to go into the loop, but also the code that fetches the user inputs, and determines *numericChoice*!

What you could do would be to write a helper method, like:

```
private int showMenuAndGetUserChoice() {
 // create a menu and display it to the user
 // then ask the user to choose an option
 String menu = "1) See Rules\n" ...
 String userChoice = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(menu);
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You chose option " + userChoice); ...

 return Integer.parseInt(userChoice);
}
```

And now you can loop much easier, by simply calling that method and checking its result within your loop body!